# Finding all matches of the object value inside chats array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a chat app and I am stuck at a query. I have chats stored inside an array of objects. I want to fetch chats matching the key of object value. I am using mongoose library to query mongodb. Please do help me in solving this.

My chat schema is:

```
chats: [
  {
    sentFrom: 'user1',
    sentTo: 'athlete1',
    message: 'hi'
  },
  {
    sentFrom : 'user2',
    sentTo: 'athlete1',
    message: 'hi athleyte'
  }
]
```

I want to find all the chats where sentFrom value is 'user1'.

This is my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvc5z.png) and it's not working.

Comment: _id is ObjectId()  you are trying to pass in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your document ,

you are doing match on whole collection and your condition is *chats.sentFrom* should be equal to *user1* that's why,
If any other document has similar kind of data in that case it will return 2 documents  in order to filter out the array you will have to use `$filter` using aggregation

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: {_id: ObjectId("5f87fec2e80b410a20c6819a")}},
    { $project: {
        chats: {$filter: {
            input: '$chats',
            as: 'chat',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$chat.sentFrom', "user1"]}
        }}
    }}
])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try filter:

```
 let result = chats.filter(chat => chat.sentFrom === 'user1');
```